# Mismo evento cuando se hace click y cuando se pulsa una tecla

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Estoy intentando aprender React haciendo una simple "maquina de sonidos".

Pues bien quiero que cuando se pulse una tecla o se haga click en cualquiera de los  *.drum-pad* se active esta clase (digamos que la clase se activaría en cada uno de los div *.drum-pad*)

```
    .onclickonkeyed{
  background: white;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 300ms linear;
   -ms-transition: background-color 300ms linear;
    transition: background-color 300ms linear;
}
```

¿Eso se puede hacer de una vez?

¿O cómo se debería hacer?

Tengo esto de momento:

```js
class DrumPad extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
  }
  render(){
    return(
      <div id="grid-keys">
        <div className="drum-pad" id="Heater-1"><audio src="" className="clip" id="Q"></audio>Q</div>
        <div className="drum-pad" id="Heater-2"><audio src="" className="clip" id="W"></audio>W</div>
        <div className="drum-pad" id="Heater-3"><audio src="" className="clip" id="E"></audio>E</div>
        <div className="drum-pad" id="Heater-4"><audio src="" className="clip" id="A"></audio>A</div>
        <div className="drum-pad" id="Clap"><audio src="" className="clip" id="S"></audio>S</div>
        <div className="drum-pad" id="Open-HH"><audio src="" className="clip" id="D"></audio>D</div>
        <div className="drum-pad" id="Kick-n'-Hat"><audio src="" className="clip" id="Z"></audio>Z</div>
        <div className="drum-pad" id="Kick"><audio src="" className="clip" id="X"></audio>X</div>
        <div className="drum-pad" id="Closed-HH"><audio src="" className="clip" id="C"></audio>C</div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
  }
  render(){
    return (
      <div id="drum-machine">
        <DrumPad />
        <div id="display">"SOUND"</div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```css
body{
  background:
linear-gradient(135deg, #708090 21px, #d9ecff 22px, #d9ecff 24px, transparent 24px, transparent 67px, #d9ecff 67px, #d9ecff 69px, transparent 69px),
linear-gradient(225deg, #708090 21px, #d9ecff 22px, #d9ecff 24px, transparent 24px, transparent 67px, #d9ecff 67px, #d9ecff 69px, transparent 69px)0 64px;
background-color:#708090;
background-size: 64px 128px;

}

#drum-machine{
  width: 40%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 30px;
  background: #8C271E;
  border: 6px solid #BD632F;
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: arial;
  display: flex;
}
#display{
  font-style: italic;
  background: #D9D1D4;
  height: 20PX;
  width: 70px;
  padding: 10px 25px 10px 25px;
  border: 2px solid #7C7C7C;
  margin-left: 60px;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
#grid-keys{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 100px);
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(50px, auto);
  grid-gap: 10px;
}
  #grid-keys .drum-pad{
    background: #D8973C;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    border-radius: 3px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
.onclickonkeyed{
  background: white;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 300ms linear;
    -ms-transition: background-color 300ms linear;
    transition: background-color 300ms linear;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Te recomiendo cambiar de enfoque. Imagina que agregues 50 tecla más; tendrías que escribir 50 `div` manualmente. Not much fun.

---

#### Componente Tecla

Crea un componente que represente una tecla. Esta tecla va a recibir como propiedad la letra que va a renderizar.

```
export class DrumPad extends React.Component {
  
  render() {
    const clazz = classnames({
      "drum-pad": true
    })
    return (
      <button className={clazz}>
        {this.props.char}
      </button>
    )
  }
}
```

Esta clase debe manejar el evento `click`. Lo que haremos será añadir la clase `active` si el botón ha sido presionado. Luego de un tiempo razonable, le quitaremos la clase.

Primero creamos el estado:

```
state = { active: false }
```

Posteriormente, creamos el método `highlight`, quien se encargará de actualizar el estado para cambiar el valor de `active`.

```
highlight = (flag, cb) => {
  this.setState({ active: flag }, cb)
}
```

Ahora, añadiremos unas variables a la clase:

- `runningAnimation`: indica si está ejecutándose la animación y evitar hacer una doble.
- `HIGHLIGHT_TIMEOUT`: indica el tiempo máximo que durará la animación.
- `sound`: variable de tipo `Audio` que nos servirá para referenciar el archivo de audio y ejecutarla.

```
HIGHLIGHT_TIMEOUT = 120 /* 0.12 segundos - duración del press */
runningAnimation = false
sound = new Audio('/ruta/al/archivo/de/sonido.wav')
```

Ahora, crearemos el método que se encargue de disparar estas acciones cuando se presione el botón:

```
activate = () => {
  if (this.runningAnimation) {
    return
  }
  this.highlight(true, () => {
    this.sound.play() // tocamos el audio
    this.runningAnimation = true
    // inmediatamente después que tocamos el audio
    // y agregamos la clase 'active', esperamos
    // 0.12s para removerla.
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.highlight(false, () => {
        this.runningAnimation = false
      })
    }, this.HIGHLIGHT_TIMEOUT)
  })
}
```

Hasta aquí ya tenemos nuestra tecla funcional. Si presionas el botón, se debe agregar la clase `active` produciendo una animación de presión y se reproduce el sonido.

#### Componente Teclado

En este componente vamos renderizar tantos componentes `DrumPad` como letras tengamos. Para esto, vamos a guardar en el estado un array de teclas:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    keys: ["Q", "W", "E", "R", "T", "Y"]
  }
  keysRefs = []
}
```

Seguido, vamos a convertirlas en componentes `DrumPad`:

```
render() {
  return (
    <div className="grid-keys">
      { this.state.keys.map(key => {
          const ref = React.createRef();
          this.keysRefs.push({
            [key.toLowerCase()]: ref
          });
          return <DrumPad key={key} char={key} ref={ref} />;
        })
      }
    </div>
  )
}
```

Y procedemos a registrar los listeners en `componentDidMount`:

```
componentDidMount() {
  document.addEventListener("keypress", this.onKeyDown)
}
```

Si te fijas, hemos creado un `ref` por cada tecla y la hemos guardado en una variable array `keysRefs`, esto nos servirá para que cuando presionemos una tecla en nuestro teclado, obtener el componente asociado a dicha tecla y poder disparar manualmente el método `activate`.

Observa la implementación de `onKeyDown`:

```
onKeyDown = e => {
  e.stopPropagation()
  const char = String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode).toLowerCase()
  // encontramos el objeto que contenga como clave, la tecla presionada
  const refObject = this.keysRefs.find(ref => ref[char])
  if (refObject) {
    const ref = refObject[char] // obtenemos el ref
    ref.current.activate() // ejecutamos el método activate de DrumPad
  }
}
```

Esto es lo interesante de los `refs`: **puedes acceder a métodos dentro de los componentes**. Esto nos permitirá usar la misma lógica tanto si el botón fue presionado o si la tecla fue la presionada.

---

#### Ejemplo

```js
class DrumPad extends React.Component {
  state = { active: false };
  HIGHLIGHT_TIMEOUT = 120;
  runningAnimation = false;
  audio = new Audio("");

  activate = () => {
    if (this.runningAnimation) {
      return;
    }
    this.highlight(true, () => {
      this.audio.play();
      this.runningAnimation = true;
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.highlight(false, () => {
          this.runningAnimation = false;
        });
      }, this.HIGHLIGHT_TIMEOUT);
    });
  };

  highlight = (flag, cb) => {
    this.setState({ active: flag }, cb);
  };

  render() {
    const clazz = classNames({
      "drum-pad": true,
      active: this.state.active
    });
    return (
      <button className={clazz} onClick={this.activate}>
        {this.props.char}
      </button>
    );
  }
}

class KeyGrid extends React.Component {
  state = {
    keys: ["Q", "W", "E", "R", "T", "Y"]
  };
  keysRefs = [];

  componentDidMount() {
    document.addEventListener("keypress", this.onKeyDown);
  }

  onKeyDown = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    const char = String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode).toLowerCase();
    const refObject = this.keysRefs.find(ref => ref[char]);
    if (refObject) {
      const ref = refObject[char];
      ref.current.activate();
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="grid-keys">
        {this.state.keys.map(key => {
          const ref = React.createRef();
          this.keysRefs.push({
            [key.toLowerCase()]: ref
          });
          return <DrumPad key={key} char={key} ref={ref} />;
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function App() {
  return (
     <KeyGrid />
  )
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

```css
html {
   box-sizing: border-box;
}
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.grid-keys {
  background: #5b626a;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
}
.grid-keys .drum-pad {
  margin: 0 5px;
}
.drum-pad {
  /* border: 2px solid #aaa; */
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background: #5b626a;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), 0 -1px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.85);
  font-size: 18px;
  /* padding: 5px 10px; */
  outline: none;
  transition: all 150ms ease;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
}
.drum-pad.active {
  background-color: #4b5157;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), 0 -1px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
  transform: translateY(2px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/classnames/2.2.6/index.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Si dejo presionada la tecla no se mantiene presionada :/

Comment: @jdnichollsc Un punto interesante para que lo tome en cuenta el OP ;)